# Editing the content of database in android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-layout, android-intent

I have a edit tab in my app where the user can edit his details given during the time of registration .Inside the edit activity i have a save button which when clicked it saves the 
data or update the datas into the database.

CODE

```
public void onSave(View btn)
{
    EditText edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNameED);
    EditText edtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassED);
    EditText edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmailED);
    EditText edtPh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPhED);
    int id=0;
    String where = DataBase_Server.C_ID+"=?";
    String[] whereArgs = {id+""};
    DataBase_Server database=new DataBase_Server(Edit.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db=database.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataBase_Server.MOBILE_NO, edtPh.getText().toString());
    values.put(DataBase_Server.PASS, edtPass.getText().toString());
    values.put(DataBase_Server.EMAIL, edtEmail.getText().toString());
    for(int i=0;i<edtName.length();i++)
    {
        id+=(int)edtName.getText().toString().charAt(i);
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,id+"  hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try
    {
        db.update(DataBase_Server.TABLE, values,where,whereArgs);
    }catch(Exception e){}
    Toast.makeText(this,"UPDATE SUCESSFULL !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
    database.close();
}
```

The code is giving not a single error but it is not even updating anything in the database. The database is not changed at all even after the user edit his details.

Comment: What datatype is the C__ID column?  String?  If so, you need to enclose the WHERE comparison value in single quotes.  You don't handle your exception for the db.update() and the toast will show "successful" whether the DB updates or not.  I bet you're getting an exception there.

Comment: can u show me how to do that ?

Comment: String[] whereArgs = {"'"id+"'"};

Answer (score 0):

You are adding up the values of all the characters in the name:

```
for(int i=0;i<edtName.length();i++)
    id+=(int)edtName.getText().toString().charAt(i);
```

This is unlikely to be your real ID value. With no record matching the `WHERE` condition, the update will do nothing, silently.

You *must* remember the ID value from when you loaded the data, because the name may have changed.